# secure key management using smart card

Tags: key-management, smartcard

I have a scenario where I want to encrypt the file data on client machine along with smart card authentication. I have followed a link that states that for smart cards, private key never leaves The card. It further explains that File data encryption should be done using on-board smart card processor with the session key generated (in smart card) and then enciphered session key is attached with the encrypted file data and is sent back to client PC. I want to know is there some standard that would explain complete procedure along with necessary security measures?

I have a scenario where session keys are generated off-board on client  machine. I want to use smart card for authentication purpose only while rest of crypto operations should be performed on client machine.  How can I achieve this? Is there any secure method of exporting private key to client machine?? like where private key is exported and used but never stored on client machine??